# Why OnMouseDown Event occur once , how to handle mouse hold event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseevent

the difference between mouse click and mouse down - that mouse click occurs only once , but mouse down occurs every tick my mouse is down

here's in my simple example - I don't know why the event occur only once , however I am using mouse down not mouse click

```
<canvas id="drawhere" onmousedown="console.log('HH')" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
```

It writes 'HH' only once !! mouse up and down again - to write it again

I need it to be written every tick as my mouse is down - any help :))

> I don't use jquery , javascript only

Comment: Please define what you are calling a "tick".

Comment: [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) only fires when the user presses a button. It doesn't fire continuously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[`mouseup` and `mousedown`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html)** are not supposed to continuously fire. They are meant to signal a single action has happened.

However, you could achieve this effect with a custom timer (**[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** to be more specific) that is triggered on `mousedown` and cancelled on `mouseup`:

```js
document.getElementById("main");

var timer = null;  // Variable to hold a reference to the timer

// Set up an event handler for mousedown
main.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt){
  // Start a timer that fires a function at 50 millisecond intervals
  timer = setInterval(function(){
    // the function can do whatever you need it to
    console.log("Mouse is down!");
  }, 50);
});

// Set up a custom mouseup event handler for letting go 
// of the mouse inside the box or when mouse leaves the box.
function mouseDone(evt){
  clearInterval(timer);         // Cancel the previously initiated timer function
  console.log("Mouse is up or outside of box!");  // And, do whatever else you need to
}

// Bind the handlers:
main.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseDone);
main.addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseDone);
```

```css
#main {
  background-color:yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">Press and hold the mouse down inside me!</div>
```

Comment: There is one thing which is missing I guess, if I pressed the mouse > dragged it outside the box > released the mouse. 

Mouse up will not fire for main and console.log will be infinite. I think mouse up should check for active mouse down and focus area also

Comment: True, but that was not the requirement specified in the question. I have updated the answer to accommodate that scenario though.

Answer (score 0):

Use "onmousemove" instead "onmouseover" and I recommend you use a function like this in your javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("drawhere").addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
    console.log("mouse event!");
});
```

Working pen:
http://codepen.io/parzibyte/full/ENzjvW/

Comment: `mousemove` won't work if the mouse is not moved while a mousebutton is continuously held down and your code pen shows that.

Comment: No - we speak about events related to mouse click - no move or over events